# Seaborn Pairplots are Running Extremely Slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, seaborn

I have a rather large dataset, around 250k rows and 140 columns.  I'm taking just the numerics from the dataframe, so I'm down to around 40 columns.

```
df = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
```

Now, I'm trying to run this code.

```
sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
df1 = df.head(1000)
g = sns.pairplot(df1)



# with regression
df1 = df.head(1000)
sns.pairplot(df1, kind="reg")
plt.show()


# without regression
df1 = df.head(1000)
sns.pairplot(df1, kind="scatter")
plt.show()
```

The problem is that all three of these plots runs for a very long time (upwards of 30 minutes each) and none of the three ever finish (to tun each, I am selecting a chunk of code and hitting Shift+Alt+E in PyCharm).  I had to terminate PyCharm and restart it 3x.  These plots are all from the link below, which I'm guessing many people here have seen many times before.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html

Comment: Are you sure you want to generate a **40x40** plot? Is this even going to be viewable in a meaningful way? If you are certain you want to do this, note that `pairplot` generates the scatterplot for `x1 vs y2` *twice*: once in the `x1` column, and once in the `y2` column. You could perhaps simplify this (and potentially speed up your code) by using a `FacetGrid` or `subplots` construction rather than `pairplot`.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty massive, I know. I'm just trying to get a sense of what things look like, and then pick the fields that I really want to keep. I started this as a feature engineering exercise and then went off on a tangent with this plotting stuff. Maybe I need to switch back to the feature engineering, determine the exact columns I need to work with, and then take it from there.